# Given a matrix, how can I quickly generate all tuples consisting of its row elements in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, tuples

Suppose there is a matrix:

[image]

Next, I take an arbitrary element from each row of the matrix, since the matrix has **m** rows in total, I end up with **m** elements.

After that, I arrange these elements together to form a tuple according to the row number from small to large, that is

[image]

Obviously, there are **2^m** such tuples in total. For example, when m=2, we will have 4 tuples, which are:

[image]

So, how can I program to generate these 2^m tuples quickly(In python)? Which algorithm should I use?

---

**Note:**

Input: An m×2 matrix

Output: 2^m tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Example:

```
In [1]: import itertools                                                                                    

In [2]: arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]                                                                      

In [3]: list(itertools.product(*arr))                                                                       
Out[3]: 
[(1, 3, 5),
 (1, 3, 6),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (1, 4, 6),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 3, 6),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (2, 4, 6)]
```